# what does "being" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does being mean in this sentence?  and also **after** looks strange to me! since isn't better?

> I have had a privileged life after being brought up in Govan?

Comment: Either remove 'after' or replace 'being' with 'having'.

Comment: @ashish7249 I'm sorry, but I don't find this to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since* might be a bit better in this case, because it has the meaning of "over the period of time that began when your upbringing was complete and continuing in the present." If you use the simple past, perhaps *after* is better:

> I had a privileged life after being brought up in Govan.

This doesn't specifically state that your privileged life continues through to the present, as the use of present perfect does.

*Being* has pretty much the meaning of *I was*.

> I had a privileged life after I was brought up in Govan.

This has the same meaning as the previous example. However, be careful of using *since* with *I was*. This sentence can have either of two meanings:

> I have had a privileged life since I was brought up in Govan.

These are the two possible meanings:

> I have had a privileged life from the time that I was brought up in Govan.
>   I have had  a privileged life because I was brought up in Govan.

If you use *being* instead of *I was*, it can only have the first meaning.